# C#.NET MSI Shortcut Launches... NUnit?

Tags: dll, build, permissions, windows-installer, shortcut

I have a build machine that regularly builds an MSI installer for my software application.  My software application consists of a number of dlls, one of which is used for testing.  Typically, the process has no problems - I can create an MSI that runs the main process, which includes all of the referenced dlls, etc.

Last week, however, the MSI that was created from the build has some odd behavior when installed.  Namely, the shortcut that is created, while pointing to the correct installation directory, launches NUnit loaded with my test dll, rather than the main process.  In a subsequent build, the MSI that was produced doesn't have that problem; When I compare the source code baselines of the two builds, I see minimal differences.

There are only differences that I notice between the two MSIs:

1. The one that actually works has the "Compatibility" tab available, whereas the the one that brings up NUnit does not.
2. The one that does NOT work has the "INTERACTIVE" group listed under the security settings.

Note: I am running on Windows 7.

---

Any ideas on what might cause this behavior?  Since there are no notable differences in the software baselines, I'm wary that the build machine must have been altered in some way between the builds, but in what way could this happen such that the problem manifests itself like this?